# jQuery - Retrieve images randomly from an array on load

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to retrieve images from an array and randomly populate the `src` of each item on load but the images return as `[object Object]`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imagesArray = [{
      id: "one",
      src: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1450/6394/products/MCS10014LS_MOCK_UP_1024x1024.png?v=1545018000"
    },
    {
      id: "two",
      src: "https://assets.bigcartel.com/product_images/191933374/tank_bikes_not_war_american_apparel__tri-oatmeal_mockup.png"
    },
    {
      id: "three",
      src: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0617/7613/products/Allday-No-Saint-Hockey-Jersey-MOCK_1024x1024.png?v=1492726972"
    }
  ];

  $(".item").each(function() {
    var randomImage =
      imagesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesArray.length)];
    $(this)
      .find("img")
      .attr("src", randomImage);
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px
}

.item img {
  max-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <img src="https://www.emergerstrategies.com/wp-content/themes/cannyon_/media/_frontend/img/grid-no-image.png">
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img src="https://www.emergerstrategies.com/wp-content/themes/cannyon_/media/_frontend/img/grid-no-image.png">
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img src="https://www.emergerstrategies.com/wp-content/themes/cannyon_/media/_frontend/img/grid-no-image.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of sampling your images array is an object like:

```
{
  id: "one",
  src: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1450/6394/products/MCS10014LS_MOCK_UP_1024x1024.png?v=1545018000"
}
```

You just need to reference the correct property from it:

```
.attr("src", randomImage.src);
```

You're seeing `[object Object]` because the attribute value is being cast to a string when it's assigned, and `object.toString()` is the string literal `"[object Object]"`:

```
({id: "one", src: "foo"}).toString()
"[object Object]"
```